# Como utilizar o foreach com a biblioteca mPdf?

Tags: php, html, relatório, mpdf

Olá, amigos.

Estou num duro problema, sei qual é, porém não consigo resolve-lo.

Bom, estou utilizando a biblioteca mPDF para gerar relatórios, ela é ótima e muito simples de usar. Estou trazendo informações do banco de dados e salvando numa table e é ela que é pra aparecer no relátorio, no entanto só gera a ultima linha dessa table e isso é obvio, pois não tem uma estrutura de repetição (foreach que estou usando) nela, consequentemente não trás todas as informações do banco.

O meu código é esse:

```
<?php
    include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
    require_once ('../Controller/crudComissao.php');

   $idFuncionario = $row['idFuncionario'];
   $nomeFuncionario = $row['nomeFuncionario'];
   $valor = $row['valor'];

if (isset($_POST['btImprimir'])) {
$html = "
     <fieldset>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='text-center'>
         <img src='img/logorelatorio.png' >
        </div>
        <br>
        <h3>Comissões</h3>
         <table class='table table-hover table-bordered'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='text-center'>Código</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Nome do Corretor</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Mês</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Valor(R$)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                   

                    <tr>
                        <td class='text-center'> $idFuncionario </td>
                        <td class='text-center'> $nomeFuncionario</td>
                        <td class='text-center'> $mes_nome </td>
                        <td class='text-center'>R$ $valor </td>
                    </tr>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align='right'>Total</td>
                        <td align='center'>R$ $sum </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
     </fieldset>";

    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $css = file_get_contents("css/cavalaro.css");
    $css = file_get_contents("css/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output("comissao.pdf",'D');
}

?>
```

Espero que tenha sido claro. Obrigado.

Comment: Também estou com o mesmo problema.
O que eu estou tentando fazer é finalizar o html e iniciar o php e depois eu concateno as váriaveis.
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html."".$html2."".$html3);

Comment: $css = file_get_contents("css/cavalaro.css");
    $css = file_get_contents("css/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css");

Duas variáveis não pode receber valores diferente pq vc vai estar sobrepondo os valor dela.